# SSH client ignoring key and falling back on password

Tags: linux, ssh, windows

I'm connecting to my server with this line:

> ssh -v -i C:\ssh\flyingclub_id_rsa -p 222 webserver@155.138.196.12

It appears to find the key.

Windows client:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2                             
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 222.     
debug1: Connection established.                                       
debug1: identity file C:\\ssh\\flyingclub_id_rsa type 0               
debug1: identity file C:\\ssh\\flyingclub_id_rsa-cert type -1         
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1          
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
OpenSSH_8.6                                                           
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000             
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:222 as 'webserver'          
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                         
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received                                     
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256                             
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256                  
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:
<implicitcompression: none                                          
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:
<implicitcompression: none                                          
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY                             
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
SHA256:EkbhtzWxf8m+y9GitYbTF8IlAZshqVLd8W4mGYs5dvg                    
debug1: Host '[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:222' is known and matches the ECDSA
host key.                                                             
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Chris/.ssh/known_hosts:2              
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks                              
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent                                         
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS                                    
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received                                     
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks                               
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or
directory                                                             
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\ssh\\flyingclub_id_rsa RSA
SHA256:cdbgYmSzYqETRvqvw6Kb6NV+rF6gcmdWiRuami4F8eY explicit           
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received                                    
debug1: kex_input_ext_info:
server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received                              
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password                       
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey                         
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\ssh\\flyingclub_id_rsa RSA
SHA256:cdbgYmSzYqETRvqvw6Kb6NV+rF6gcmdWiRuami4F8eY explicit           
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password                       
debug1: Next authentication method: password                          
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or
directory                                                             
webserver@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

Linux client:

```
ssh -vv -i /home/ns2/.ssh/flyingclub_id_rsa -p 222 webserver@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ns2/.ssh/flyingclub_id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/ns2/.ssh/flyingclub_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:222 as 'webserver'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EkbhtzWxf8m+y9GitYbTF8IlAZshqVLd8W4mGYs5dvg
debug1: Host '[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ns2/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ns2/.ssh/flyingclub_id_rsa RSA SHA256:b1i1axYBeTcJsY+RvspQkMhrea4dquFHOzvsjihKgZQ explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ns2/.ssh/flyingclub_id_rsa RSA SHA256:b1i1axYBeTcJsY+RvspQkMhrea4dquFHOzvsjihKgZQ explicit
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
webserver@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

I'm not quite certain what it exactly has a problem with.

My key was generated on the client using: ssh-keygen
And copied using cockpit on Fedora.

Have I generated my key wrong?

---

Thank you for pointing towards server logs:

> journalctl -u sshd |tail -100

`Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory ...`

Answer (score 3):

The logs from your answer are pretty self explanatory. Although you didn't paste the full output to see which directory it is, you probably have wrong permissions on the .ssh directory or the authorized_keys file on the server.

SSH doesn’t like it if your home or ~/.ssh directories have group write permissions. Your home directory should be writable only by you, ~/.ssh should be 700, and authorized_keys should be 600

```
chmod go-w /home/user
chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Replace /home/user with the actual user on the system, which judging by the commands should be *webserver* . Also, make sure the user and group are correct as well, on the .ssh directory and authorized_keys file